# Why can I not make successfully ? (BBB AccessPoint problems)

Tags: makefile, beagleboneblack, access-point

I am trying to follow this guide -> http://bogeskov.dk/UsbAccessPoint.html to make my Beaglebone Black act as a Access Point.

So I got to the point where I use the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-...
git clone https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu.git
cd rt8192cumakesudo make install
```

Problem comes when I try and run "make". I got an error that a file named "build" was missing.
So I tried to install the kernel-headers with this url that is actually the right one for my BeagleBone OS :
https://rcn-ee.net/deb/wheezy-armhf/v3.8.13-bone47/linux-headers-3.8.13-bone47_1.0wheezy_armhf.deb

Then I ran dpkg -i linux-headers-3.8.13-bone47_1.0wheezy_armhf.deb and it looked like it finished.
So when I go back into the rt8192cu folder I tried running "make" again.So then I received a different error.

```
 Makefile:580: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.13-bone47/arch/armv7l/Makefile: No such file or directory
 make[1]: *** No Rule to make target ' /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.13-bone47/arch/armv7l/Makefile '. Stop
```

How can I get this to make successfully ?
I just want to use my Beaglebone as a Access point

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replies.
It turns out that if you use MAKE for this driver and you are on a BeagleBone Black you need to give it the paramter
" ARCH=arm ".
You will also have to fix the Timerx.h header. It is quite a common problem it seems.

After that it should compile fine.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you need to install the package `linux-kbuild`, that provide the necessary toolset to compile kernel modules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but
    sudo apt-get install linux-kbuild 
does not seem to work. It just says cant locate package.

Comment: Ok soo if you would like to install kbuild the command is simply " sudo apt-get install kbuild ".
Even though that installed it still did not solve my problem.

Comment: `kbuild` is completely different. `linux-kbuild` package is what's required on my Debian Linux to build kernle modules. But it seems that this package does not exist on e.g. Ubuntu. What distro do you use?